# Can not migrate on Matic network: There was a timeout while attempting to connect to the network

Tags: truffle, polygon

I am trying to deploy my smart contracts on the Matic Mumbai testnet. Please find below my truffle-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['solidity-coverage'],
  migrations_directory: './dist/migrations',
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1', // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: '*', // Any network (default: none)
    },
    matic: {
      networkCheckTimeout: 10000, 
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.today`),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true,
      
    },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    //timeout: 100000,
    reporter: 'eth-gas-reporter',
    reporterOptions: {
      excludeContracts: ['Migrations'],
    },
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: solcconfig.version,
      settings: {
        optimizer: solcconfig.optimizer,
        evmVersion: solcconfig.evmVersion,
      },
    },
  },

  db: {
    enabled: false,
  },
};
```

But somehow I can’t connect to the network: Error: There was a timeout while attempting to connect to the network. any idea?
I tried to google it and changed https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.today by https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today but then I have an other error. Thanks for the help!

Version:
Truffle version: v5.4.0
Nodejs: v14.16.0

Comment: Matic is a congested network already, I would install my own `bor` & `heimdall` processes

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the rpc url to

```
// Mainnet
"https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/"
// Testnet
"https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ramalingam but then I have the following error message: `--only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC`

Comment: try adding  chainid to the transaction object, `'chainId': 80001`,
refer here:  (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94412/valueerror-code-32000-message-only-replay-protected-eip-155-transac)