# transaction on the "goerli" chain

Tags: goerli

When I try to transaction on the "goerli" chain,the method "eth_sendRawTransaction" response "only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC", how i can get the  right answer？

Comment: Try to run the node with `--rpc.allow-unprotected-txs` check this [link] (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94412/valueerror-code-32000-message-only-replay-protected-eip-155-transac)

Comment: Thanks! Will try

Comment: It seems you are using the "old" standard to sign transactions. To avoid replaying attacks you should try using the "new" EIP-155 standard for signing the transactions.